# bash: Meteor.users: command not found

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working through the Your First Meteor Application tutorial:

1. I ran this command: `meteor add accounts-password`
2. I received the expected output
3. I ran this command: `Meteor.users`
4. I received this unexpected output: bash: Meteor.users: command not found

Can someone explain this error and provides a suggestion on how to fix it?

[image: expected output]

Comment: Type that into the browser's console, not into the shell.

Comment: @DavidWeldon...thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the command `meteor shell` before getting access to the Meteor server shell.